# How do I get my Twitter feed to integrate with a blog (with individual comment threads)?

Tags: twitter, comments, customization, blogs

I would like to create a blog where my Twitter updates essentially create blog posts, with a comment thread. If there isn't blog software that does this right now (I did some searching but couldn't find the commenting aspect) what would be the simplest approach and starting blog software to do this?

Potentially an alternate approach to this would be a blog interface that could auto-update my Twitter feed with the title text.

Whatever the solution, I'd like it to be fully automated so that it is roughly no more work than currently updating my Twitter feed using the Twitter web interface. Note: I'm also interested in 'normal' blog posting via the default blog web admin interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use Wordpress, you can use the [Twitter Tools](http://alexking.org/projects/wordpress) plugin.

> "Pull your tweets into your blog and create new tweets on blog posts and from within WordPress."

Each tweet/blog post would automatically have comments enabled.

Good luck man,

Brian Gianforcaro

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com) or [Sweetcron](http://www.sweetcron.com/) with [Disqus](http://disqus.com) comments. You can auto-import your Twitter/Flickr/any RSS feed. You can also post text/audio/video from the site admin. You'll have to manually add Disqus comments, but then each post or Twitter message will have its own threaded comments.